# Optimal location of a point on an ellipse

Tags: geometry

> Consider an ellipse $4x^2+13y^2=52$ and variable point $N(k, 12-2k)$ is taken in such a way that angle $F_1NF_2$ is maximum, where $F_1$ and $F_2$ are the foci of the given ellipse then value of $F_1N/F_2N$ is

Comment: wouldn't the ratio be $1$ by symmetry?

Answer (score 2):

Angle $\angle F_1NF_2$ is constant when $N$ lies on a circle passing through $F_1=(-3,0)$ and $F_2=(3,0)$, the smaller the radius $r$ of the circle the largest the angle, because $\displaystyle\sin(\angle F_1NF_2)={F_1F_2\over 2r}$.

But point $N$ is constrained on the line $y=12-2x$,
hence a maximum angle is attained when the circle is tangent to that line at point $N$.

Let $B=(6,0)$ be the point where the line meets the $x$ axis; 
from power of a point we get 
$$BN=\sqrt{BF_1\cdot BF_2}=3\sqrt3, 
\quad\hbox{whence}\quad 
N=(6-3\sqrt{3/5},6\sqrt{3/5}).$$ 
From that it is easy to find the required ratio:
$F_1N/F_2N=\sqrt3$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I attacked this one using numerical methods and found the answer is $\sqrt {3}.$  I would be interested to see a more elegant answer.

$k = 3.67621\\
N = (3.67621, 4.64758)\\
F_1 (-3,0)\\
F_2 = (3,0)\\
F_1N^2 = 66.17178\\
F_2N^2 = 22.05726$

Comment: @AbcDef thanks for the correction on the focus.  As I said, I found them numerically.  i.e. set up the equations in a spreadsheet and plugged different values for k, until I found the one that maximised the angle.